# SSH connection timeout after changing SSH port and enabling ufw on tun0

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, ufw

I am trying to connect SSH via VPN, and with ufw enabled.

I changed the SSH port from 22 to 53535

I changed the value in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, restarted the sshd, and connect with:

ssh root@192.168.x.x -p 53535

and it worked well

Then, I have set ufw:

```
[root@artik log]# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
53535                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
9090                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
1883                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
53535 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
9090 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
1883 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

so ufw is allowing 53535 in

I have an issue activating logs, so I can't really see what's going on.

EDIT: I have resetted the firewall with `ufw reset` and then, allowed the default incoming policy

I have also set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` in `/etc/default/ufw` so I have now

```
[root@artik log]# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

So, it seems my firewall is quite useless, but even like that, I still get a timeout with

```
ssh root@192.168.x.x -p 53535
```

Any idea what's going on?